# Select element out of JSON-File in Mathematica

Tags: json, select, time-series, wolfram-mathematica, element

I would like to select an element out of a JSON file in Mathematica, however, I have never done it before and thus don't know how to proceed.

After import the data from a web server, the data look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXgtf.png)

Now I would like to select all elements which come after "close ->", hence the closing price and generate a list to plot the historical price chart afterwards.

Does someone know how it works?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Alex

Comment: Use `json[[All, "date"]]`. Have you seen http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Great, thank you! :)